# Dynamic identity provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, identityserver4, duende-identity-server

I have to realize a dynamic identity provider on my project the idea is very simple (the admin of the system can add any identity provider to enable the user's login with this provider for example he can add google than users can login to the system using google all of this in runtime.
I'm using duende identity server configured with entity framework I read the documentation of
duende software but I did not get the idea.
the documentation Link: https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/ui/login/dynamicproviders/

Comment: To implement a dynamic identity provider in Duende Identity Server, create a model for provider configuration, store configurations in a data store, implement a dynamic provider API, and register a custom dynamic provider store. Enable the dynamic provider UI in the configuration and handle external provider sign-in and callback to allow users to log in with various external providers at runtime. For detailed steps, refer to the provided Duende Identity Server documentation .